# from pptx.enum.action import PP_ACTION

Tags: python, python-pptx

I just want to put an Hiperlink in my pptx so I find that I have to put this code:

```
r.text = 'link to python-pptx @ GitHub'
hlink = r.hyperlink
hlink.address = 'https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx'
```

And what I have understand is that .add_run() comes from the module: *from pptx.enum.action import PP_ACTION*, but my program doesn't find the module action in pptx.enum, somebody knows what's wrong?
Thank you so much

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match the problem you're describing. Can you change your code to show how you're trying to use PP_ACTION, how you're importing it and what the exact error is you're getting?